# Recover Deleted Rows in OUTPUT clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, output, recover

I ran the following query in SSMS without capturing the result in table variable. Is there any way I can get the deleted row using temporay created DELETED table? I have not closed the SQL session. I am in the same session where I have ran the following query.

```
delete from [AdventureWorksDW2014].[dbo].[FactCallCenter]
output deleted.*
where FactCallCenterID = 119
```

Comment: Has SSMS captured the outputted rows into its results grid (note that the text result stream might be showing given that it's a delete query. If you can see "10000 rows affected", press Ctrl-D to switch to datagrid view)? There is no OUTPUT INTO here so these rows haven't been put into anything that SQLServer knows about

Comment: If you have the results window open, you could copy that data into something, and turn them into DDL and DML statements, otherwise nope, they are gone. You'll need to `RESTORE` the database to a point prior to the `DELETE`.

Comment: Caius - Yes I was able to see the result in the grid.

Comment: Larnu - Yes the window is open. Can you give me SQL to copy data as you have said?

Answer (score 1):

No, the resultset from `OUTPUT` without `INTO` goes straight to the client like any other `SELECT`. So you should be able to see the in SSMS if you have not run another query since.

If you need to undelete rows, restore from backup. Failing that, find software that can replay the transaction log. Make sure the transaction log is not truncated by backup software in the interim.